# Get value from an input field and pass into update_meta_data as $meta_value

Tags: plugins, posts, woocommerce-offtopic, email, post-meta

I am building a woocommerce site and I have some input fields the on the product page. one is for recipient email (its for a gift car). Everything works, and the recipient email is saved on the order, but I want to be able to pass the email address to a function to update_meta_data so that I can use in other parts of the code (namely to send out a separate email to the recipient to redeem the card).

here is the function I am trying to use:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta',function( $order_id, $posted ) {

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $order->update_meta_data( 'recipient_email', "joe@acme.com" );
    $order->save();
} , 10, 2);
```

Where "joe@acme" is, I want to pass the value from the form. the form is rendered using a custom form plugin. the html of the form looks like this:

```
<input name="recipient_email" id="recipient_email" data-type="text" data-req="on" data-message="no email" maxlength="255" style="width: 100%; padding: 0px;" type="text">
```

As I said, the form works to save the recipient email to the order, but not as post meta data, so I don't know how to retrieve and store as a variable that I can use for for other parts of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$posted` parameter to get the right value in your function.

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta',function( $order_id, $posted ) {

$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
$order->update_meta_data( 'recipient_email', $posted['recipient_email'] );
$order->save();
} , 10, 2);
```

Verify that $posted is an array not an object with a var_dump on $posted.
if it's an object replace `$posted['recipient_email']` with `$posted->recipient_email`

Hope it helps :)

Comment: thanks. I think I am trying to do this at the wrong place in the workflow. either as array or object, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: You need to make à var_dump($posted); to check if the variable is populated. Did not test it before my answer

Comment: You can also try to use the save_post action to save the form values.

Comment: var dump on $posted is empty.